# render html from database using javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I have a dynamic page which has repeating input text fields and is build using Jquery. I use C#.net to get the data to be displayed on the input fields. My question is on how do I handle single Quotes and double quotes while rendering the input field. I create jquery string on page render and uses that to render the input fields on the page. But if any of the input fields contains a html tag with double quotes then it screws up the whole page. Let me know I this make sense or need more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I would return a "safe" string from within the C# that escapes quotes or converts them into html entities.

A quote as a html entity looks like this:
`&quot;`.

An escaped quote has a blackslash in front of it like so: `\"`.

You shouldn't rely on Javascript to do this, let your CMS do the work for you!

Comment: The client wants the quotes to be displayed on the frontend. Is there anything similar to CDATA in xml for HTML so that the HTML tags are ignored by the web page.

Comment: Escaping or converting the quotes into html entities will mean they are shown on the front end, they just won't be interpreted as a literal quote which will affect JS.